# Django Bad File Descriptor on live server

Tags: python, django

So, I will make this quick.

When servicing the Django app onto a live serve and when it processes the views.py script, when ever there is a print statement from time to time a bad file descriptor error will pop up.

I have found this very annoying and hard to fix, while still keeping the print statements.

The way to resolve it is to simply refresh the page and the view works again and like nothing ever happened.

I have been Googling and seems no info has shed light to resolve this.

Comment: Do you re-assign `sys.stdout` to something else?

Comment: Nope. I did not change with any sys output related stuff.